# Partially applying a group of functions

Tags: haskell

I am working on designing a Haskell module that is designed solve a math problem, which may have various parameterizations. The module exports a function:

```
run_and_output_parameterization :: ProblemParams -> String -> IO ()
```

where the idea is that `ProblemParams` objects will be generated in some "controller" and called as follows:

```
map (\(pp, name) -> run_and_output_parameterization pp name) (zip pp_list names_list)
```

My question is, within the module, there are some functions such as indexing functions which I would like to partially apply for a particular parameterization. For example,

```
evenly_spaced_point_approx :: Int -> Int -> Int -> Double -> Double -> Int
evenly_spaced_point_approx xmin xmax xstep_i xstep_d target = pt
  where
    pt = max (min  (round (target/xstep_d) * xstep_i) xmax) xmin

evenly_spaced_si_approx target = evenly_spaced_point_approx (_pp_si_min pp) (_pp_si_max pp) (_pp_nstep_s pp) (_pp_nstep_sd pp) target
evenly_spaced_wi_approx target = evenly_spaced_point_approx (_pp_wi_min pp) (_pp_wi_max pp) (_pp_nstep_w pp) (_pp_nstep_wd pp) target
```

I would like to use the functions `evenly_spaced_si_approx` and `evenly_spaced_wi_approx` within the module for a particular ProblemParameter data structure (called `pp`).

Is there a way I can tell Haskell to partially apply all dependent functions, or is this something I have to do by hand? Also, my apologies for being imprecise with the functional programming terminology.

Comment: What do you mean by dependent functions?  Do you mean passing in certain argument automatically?  Depending on the definition of the function you're wanting to use, you could leverage point-free notation, but that isn't always the way to go.

Comment: My idea was that my `run_and_output_parameterization` function is the root of a DAG of functions, all of which need the ProblemParameterization object. I wanted to see if I could avoid passing it around everywhere.

Comment: Sounds like you need the `Reader` monad.  I'll provide an example as an answer.

Comment: Just a thought: `map (\(a, b) -> f a b) (zip xs ys)` can be simplified to `map (uncurry f) (zip xs ys)` and subsequently to `zipWith f xs ys`.

Comment: Oh yeah, `zipWith`. Thank you for the reminder!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a lot of functions that need the same parameter, and that's the only (or last) parameter they take then you can take advantage of the `Monad` instance for `(->) r`.  Alternatively, you can wrap everything in the `Reader` monad, whose definition is basically

```
newtype Reader r a = Reader { runReader :: r -> a }

instance Monad (Reader r) where
    return a = Reader $ \_ -> a
    m >>= f = Reader $ \r -> runReader (f (runReader m r)) r
```

Which, compared to the `Monad` instance for `(->) r`:

```
instance Monad ((->) r) where
    return a = const a
    m >>= f = \r -> f (m r) r
```

How can you use this?  For example, if you had a single parameter `pp :: ProblemParams`, then you could write functions as

```
-- Some declarations
smallFunc1 :: ProblemParams -> Double
smallFunc2 :: ProblemParams -> Double
smallFunc3 :: Int -> ProblemParams -> Double

doStuff :: ProblemParams -> Double -- Just a random return type
doStuff = do                       -- Keep the parameter implicit
    result1 <- smallFunc1          -- The ProblemParams are automatically passed
    result2 <- smallFunc2
    result3 <- smallFunc3 10
    return $ result1 + result2 + result3
```

And this works quite well, you just have to make sure that all of `smallFunc1`, `smallFunc2`, and `smallFunc3 10` take a `ProblemParams` as their last parameter (notice the inclusion of `10` with `smallFunc3`).  The `Monad` instance for functions will pass that parameter implicitly in all the binds.  Think of it as returning a value before that value has been computed.  You get to bind the "future" return value of `smallFunc1` to `result1`.

---

Alternatively, you could use the `Reader` monad:

```
type Problem a = Reader ProblemParams a

reader :: (r -> a) -> Reader r a
reader f = do
    r <- ask
    return $ f r
-- reader f = ask >>= return . f

smallFunc1' :: Problem Double
smallFunc1' = reader smallFunc1

smallFunc2' :: Problem Double
smallFunc2' = reader smallFunc2

smallFunc3' :: Int -> Problem Double
smallFunc3' i = reader (smallFunc3 i)

doStuff :: ProblemParams -> Double
doStuff pp = flip runReader pp $ do
    result1 <- smallFunc1'
    result2 <- smallFunc2'
    result3 <- smallFunc3' 10
    return $ result1 + result2 + result3
```

The reason why we have to create a `reader` function that lifts our primitives to the `Reader` monad is that `Reader` is actually defined in terms of the transformer `ReaderT` as

```
type Reader r a = ReaderT r Identity a
```

around the `Identity` monad.

Whichever you decide to use is up to you.  I think most people would be more familiar with the `Reader` version, and if you decided to stack on some more transformers later it'd be really simple.  The `Reader` monad basically helps to make the function signatures look monadic, since `ProblemParams -> Double` doesn't look like a normal monad signature.  It will use a bit more code, but it may be that it helps you reason about your program.

---

Note: I haven't run any of this code, so be warned that small errors may exist.  If anyone spots a problem, just let me know and I'll fix it.

---

An example with the `Par` monad and `ReaderT`:

```
type App a = ReaderT ProblemParams Par a

runApp :: ProblemParams -> App a -> a
runApp pp app = runPar $ runReaderT app pp
```

Then you can simply use `lift` to raise `Par` actions to `App` actions:

```
parReader :: (ProblemParams -> Par a) -> App a
parReader f = do
    r <- ask
    lift $ f r
-- parReader f = ask >>= lift . f

doStuff :: ProblemParams -> Double
doStuff pp = runApp pp $ do
    result1 <- parReader parAction1
    result2 <- parReader parAction2
    result3 <- parReader (parAction3 10)
    return $ result1 + result2 + result3
```

I'm about 99% sure that the monad stack will not affect your parallelism at all, since the `Reader` monad executes first, essentially applying your `ProblemParams` to all the functions, then it runs the `Par` action.

Comment: @stevejb Does this solve the problem you were having completely, or do you have further questions?

Comment: I think that this covers it for now. In the `doStuff` function in my actual program, I was planning to use parMap from `Control.Monad.Par` to do a parallel map. This won't be an issue will it?

Comment: @stevejb You could use the `ReaderT` transformer on top of the `Par` monad, I'll edit my answer with an example (that I'll make sure works first)

Comment: This is above and beyond helpful. Thank you bheklilr!